# Sum of Combinations with Variable Sample Size

Tags: combinatorics

I was working on a problem and this specific sum came up. I've tried simplifying it or evaluating it with no luck, and a quick search didn't get me what I'm looking for. Essentially, I need the sample size to change on each term:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{{i}\choose{k}}, k\in\mathbb{N}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that 
$$\binom{i}{k} = 0$$
when $k > i$ since it is not possible to select a subset with more elements than the set contains.  Hence,
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \binom{i}{k} = \sum_{i = k}^{n} \binom{i}{k}$$

We will show that 
$$\sum_{i = k}^{n} \binom{i}{k} = \binom{n + 1}{k + 1}$$
The right hand side counts the number of $k + 1$ element subsets of a set with $n + 1$ elements.  It remains to show that the left hand side counts the same quantity.

Consider $k + 1$ element subsets of the set $S_{n + 1} = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n, n + 1\}$ with largest element $i + 1$.  Observe that for such a subset to exist, $k \leq i \leq n$.  In order to form a $k + 1$ element subset of $S_{n + 1}$ with largest element $i + 1$, we must select $k$ of the $i$ elements in the subset $S_i = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, i\} \subseteq S_{n + 1}$, which can be done in $\binom{i}{k}$ ways.  Hence, the number of $k + 1$ element subsets of the set $S_{n + 1}$ is
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \binom{i}{k} = \binom{n + 1}{k + 1}$$

This is known as the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).